# Kubuntu 19.04 - Wired Network drops at 1000 Mbps speed

Tags: ethernet, 19.04

Yesterday i made a sudo apt update and reboot. Later i realized my speed was kind of slow so i checked in Network Interfaces Gui setting was at:

- allow auto-negotiate: unchecked
- speed: 100 Mbits/s
- duplex: half

Then decided to check the firts option and wired connection began to connected/disconnected back and forth.

Tried setting it to manual with no results.
This is the output of ethtool:

```
Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    MDI-X: on (auto)
```

Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes

I tried with another laptop and speed works at 1000 Mbps so why mine doesn't since it was ok.